# Адаптировать древне-русский

Tags: славянизмы, др.-русский

...Или церк.-славянский: **Тлят обычаи благи беседы злы**.

Цитата из Библии, но не подкреплена числами: книжка местами пострадала. Как можно перевести, уложившись в размер оригинала?

Comment: А почему "древне-русский" Вы пишете через дефис?

Comment: Насчет дефиса. Такое написание встречается в старых источниках (до середины XX века). Я могу объяснит только этим. Но сейчас это нонсенс, конечно.

Comment: А как Вы объясняете слитное написание таких слов, как "древнерусский, старославянский"?

Answer (score 1):

Это 1 Кор. 15, 33. В Синодальном переводе - *худые сообщества развращают добрые нравы*.

Если пытаться сохранить стиль, можно попробовать что-то вроде - *зло слово праведность ничтожит*

Comment: Мне ваш перевод понравился. Хотя синодальный все-таки классический.))